# Cocos2d 2.1, file loading returns null

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Here is my code. Worked in Cocos2d 2.0 and same code returns null in 2.1beta

```
const GLchar * fragmentSource = (GLchar*) [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[CCFileUtils fullPathFromRelativePath:@"CSEGrass.fsh"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] UTF8String];
```

Already added CSEGrass.fsh to xcode target. Why returns null?

Comment: check that the file is in the copy files build phase

Comment: thanks alot sir...now just added manually in Copy Bundle resources and worked. fullPathFromRelativePath is depricated...don't know whats alternative for that...

Comment: fullPathForFilenameIgnoringResolutions

Comment: no api named fullPathForFilenameIgnoringResolutions